# JavaScript show Sq lite Error on data insert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Am Trying to show a SQL error in a alert if caught but am not sure where am i going wrong if i add the error handler nothing is showing up though there is a Duplicate entry of value's in a unique column.

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ko7qun42/)

```
 var db = openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "demo", 200000);

            db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (Slno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, column1 TEXT UNIQUE, column2 TEXT UNIQUE, column3 TEXT UNIQUE, column4 TEXT UNIQUE, column5 TEXT UNIQUE)");
        });
```

Insert Query:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test (column1, column2 ,column3, column4,column5) VALUES ('insert1','insert2','insert3','insert4','insert5'),  
('insert1','insert2','insert3','insert4','insert5');",errorHandler);
});
```

Error Handler:

```
function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
    alert("Error : " + error.message);
}
```

Comment: Do your browser support SQL? My Firefox 41.0 said `ReferenceError: openDatabase is not defined` in the demo.

Comment: Am using google chrome it does support and i do have defined open database on first line `var db = openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "demo", 200000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read [SQLTransaction - JavaScript API Documentation](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html5/sqltransaction.md.html) and found that this code may work.

```
 var db = openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "demo", 200000);

            db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (Slno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, column1 TEXT UNIQUE, column2 TEXT UNIQUE, column3 TEXT UNIQUE, column4 TEXT UNIQUE, column5 TEXT UNIQUE)");
        },errorHandler);

db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test (column1, column2 ,column3, column4,column5) VALUES ('insert1','insert2','insert3','insert4','insert5'),('insert1','insert2','insert3','insert4','insert5');");
        },errorHandler);


function errorHandler(error) {
    alert("Error : " + error.message);
}
```

- `errorHandler` should be passed not to `tx.executeSql` but to `db.transaction`
- the `error` object is passed as first argument of `errorHandler`, not second one.

This code worked on my Google Chrome 45.0.2454.99 m (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `null` for the optional `arguments` and `callback` parameters to executeSql() before passing `errorHandler`:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO ...", null, null, errorHandler);
```

As specified in the [Web SQL working note](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#executing-sql-statements), the SQLTransaction.executeSql() method has the following signature:

```
void executeSql(in DOMString sqlStatement,
                in optional ObjectArray arguments,
                in optional SQLStatementCallback callback,
                in optional SQLStatementErrorCallback errorCallback);
```

So if you are not going to specify `arguments` or `callback`, then you need to pass `null`.

Here is an updated JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ko7qun42/2/

Alternatively, you could pass the `errorCallback` to the transaction() method:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
  //...
}, errorHandler);
```

However, your `errorHandler` callback would need to be modified slightly because only the SQLError would be passed to the callback.

Here is an updated JSFiddle showing this alternative approach:  http://jsfiddle.net/ko7qun42/1/